# Start an activity from any other app

Tags: android

I'm designing an app composed two activities. The first one always run, and is asked to trigger a second one when some stuff happens. This works fine with the standard code used for running activities:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, allarme.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

however, the activity in allarme.class is not started if i'm using another app (i.e. gmail),
whilel it works perfectly from home or when the screen is locked.
I'm sure that the first activity is still running, it's just that the second action is not triggered.

Should I change anything in the manifest file to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear about what you want.
but I guess you want to run two activities simultaneously, am I right?
while one activity run in background and one activity update the UI.

always keep in mind that Android architecture only allowed one activity to run at the time. If you want to pass the data from Asynchronous Task, you can call the method from that class and let your handler 'recent' class update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background service that always run at background even if you are using another app or phone is locked. Here is link for more help :
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Well, the first activity runs ok even when using other apps. What i need is to popup a dialog, wait for user input, and then come back to the previous activity or to another one that runs in background.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I think I solved it.
Basically, I found out that an activity already running can be brought to focus when re-started with a basic startActivity. Then I can immediatley switch to the new activity without losing the focus.